# How to Get Emacs to Properly Handle C Preprocessor Conditionals

Tags: c, emacs, editor, elisp, code-formatting

I have a performance sensitive CUDA code, which I'm using

```
#ifdef DEBUG_<NAME_OF_SECTION>
   ...
#else
   ...
#endif
```

...conditionals to encapsulate speed-crippling debugging code, which grabs extra info off the GPU.

Everything goes well in emacs (Centos 6.0) up until the `#else`.

This deindents (by 1 tab) the text inside the else clause of the preprocessor conditional and continues to deindent everything afterwards.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
**Note:**
`)` replication inside preprocessor conditionals seems to be properly handled by the C-mode.  But `);` duplication breaks things, forcing you to move the `);` outside the conditional ... oh dear how inconsistent.  I'm keeping this question open until we get proper elisp code to fix this inconsistency.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**NOTE on current answer:**
*[Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt) has provided inaccurate information in claiming that indenting nested `)` inside conditionals is "impossible".  It is not only possible, but Emacs' C-Mode actively does this.  Note the proper indentation of the example c program at the end of this question post for proof of that.  So it would stand to reason that `);` is also feasible to indent, though caution should be exercised for the reasons outlined by [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt).*

*Anyhow, I want to make sure people see that statement is incorrect, so they do not think this question is unanswerable.  I will remove this comment and my downvote on Jens' post when he amends his inaccurate statements to reflect that it is possible, is implemented in C-mode for the very case of `)` he outlines, but is not recommended.*

Currently I'm resorting to manually respacing things forward one tab, but it's wasting a lot of time (the code is long).

Any idea what I can add to my  ~/.emacs file to fix this???

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**
I should mention that the clause it seems to be choking on is a function closing, e.g.

```
      MyFunc<<<Blk,Thr>>>(Stuff1,
  #ifdef DEBUG_FUNC1
                          Stuff2,
                          dev_Debug);
  #else
                       Stuff2); //Deindents here.
  #endif
  //Everything here on out is deindented.
```

It may be a specific failure on that kind of code structure...

**EDIT 2**
Here's a simply C code version... the code works as expected, but not the deindent on the last `#else` clause...

```
#include <stdio.h>

//#define DEBUG

void printer
(int A,
#ifdef DEBUG
 int B,
 int C)
#else
 int B)
#endif
{
#ifdef DEBUG
   printf("A: %i, B: %i, C: %i\n", A, B, C);
#else
   printf("A: %i, B: %i\n", A, B);
#endif
}

int main()
{
   int A = -3;
   int B = 1;
   int C = 3;
   printer(A,
#ifdef DEBUG
       B,
       C);
#else
   B);
#endif
   return 0;
}
```

...that's along the lines of what I'm doing.  I know it works syntactically in C (or at least I think does... it gives correct results), however emacs doesn't like that #else clause inside the function call....

Comment: If you count the number of opening and closing braces (`{}`) in the code between the `#ifdef` and the `#else`, do they all match?

Comment: See the example... there are no `{}`... in the preprocessor section that it's choking on.  It seems to not like me using the preprocessor else within a function call. Post a non-CUDA example so I can show what I mean...

Comment: Consider putting more (e.g. a duplicate definition if required) in each branch. I suspect it is due to the ")" in the first path.

Comment: Squiggly or square braces (`[]`) or parentheses, it doesn't matter, it has to be matching number of opening and closing. Emacs C and C++ modes are stupid in a way that the don't really parse the code in the buffer the same way as for example MS Visual Studio does. Therefore constructs such as the one you have will make Emacs indent wrong.

Comment: @Joachim ... while I agree with you based on the above experience about the emacs C mode being stupid in some cases (as it butchers my valid syntax but accepts the alternative equivalent syntax proposed by Jens below).  That said, the code I'm formatting was done by a colleague in VS and the formatting is atrocious tab-wise.  Emacs may not handle everything properly, but at least its formatting is kind to narrow-default width, lightweight Linux style editors, in my experience -- better than VS in that regard.

Comment: And I know you can set up VS to give neatly formatted narrow-width editor friendly, space-indented only code, I'm just saying that people who use VS seem to be Windows geared and disregard neat spacing.... I guess that's what I mean. :P

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in the logic of your code. Logically you have different parameters in a function parameter list. The closing parenthesis should not be part of the conditional.

```
 MyFunc<<<Blk,Thr>>>(
                      Stuff1,
 #ifdef DEBUG_FUNC1
                      Stuff2,
                      dev_Debug
 #else
                      Stuff2
 #endif
                      );
```

Or alternatively you should have two complete versions of the prototype that are chosen according to your debug macro. Everthing else is not only difficult to parse for emacs (or probably any other editor) but also for the poor human that comes after you.

What you want is not possible since the indentation level of a code might depend on the macros:

```
#if A
(
#endif
something
#if B
)
#endif
```

where `A` and `B` are the same for all valid compilations. Emacs can't know without assuming values for `A` and `B`, how to indent.

Comment: My code is syntactically correct and compiles... it may be bad form, but I include a `);` cap on each closing arg-set. Without turning this into a debate about coding standards, why can't elisp handle it if it's syntactically correct.

Comment: See the simple C example above if you don't believe me about the syntax working.  Now, your solution does work, but I'd like to try to get an answer as to why emacs c handler butchers my alternative, but valid syntax and how to prevent that... until I get that answer this question remains open out of principle, but I'm rating you up as I'm using your solution as a work-around. ;)

Comment: @Jason, because elisp is lisp. Its parser is deeply dependent of scanning for closing parenthesis (in a broad sense). C is different, it parses the code in phases and syntactically replaces (or eliminates) parts of text. Somehow you want to have the identation of the code for any possible value of the preprocessor macros. For a given blob, there is no guarantee that the indentation computed that way is even something unique.

Comment: One more note... if you notice, the #else properly handles similar `)` blocks for the function definition in my examples... so even if that's the "preferred" way, it makes no sense that the C-mode wouldn't set that ground rule and follow it consistently...

Comment: I guess that's the really confusing part to me.  Why is it accepting of `)` replication, but not `);`??  I guess it's just really inconsistent, or something!  Also, seems like there has to be some way of fixing this in my `.emacs` file, which is what I asked for!  It may be long and painful exercise in elisp, but I'm sure you can do it, now that you know what the issue case is.

Comment: Your latest edit makes sense, unfortunately that's now how emacs' C-mode works... it does allow duplicate `)` INSIDE the condition in function declarations... so there is clearly special case logic built in and this must be somehow possible... again look at the simpler C example, and you should see this...

Comment: Until you acknowledge that your above statement is untrue my vote is in the downwards direction.  Not trying to be mean, but you deleted my perfectly valid edit in which I explain this to you.

Comment: To be clear your statement that it's bad form may be accurate, but the fact of the matter is that C-mode does support indenting for the very case you demonstrated above as being "impossible".  "Impossible" is absolutely not the right word to use here, as C-mode DOES THAT!  See the func. decl. in my last example... this should be obvious.  You could word your comment "is not recommend, and here's why:"... or something like that.  But please correct your inaccuracy, which you tried to obscure by deleting my edits to your post.

Comment: @Jason: edits are reviewed by users with privilege to view the [suggested edits queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits). Your edit was rejected by _two_ people: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/217376 (I also cast a `reject` vote but I was too late -- the other two beat me to it). Don't try to reply to questions or answers through edits; [the original wiki used that approach](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RandomPages), and it made the entire site unreadable for all except the authors. Your edit would make more sense as an edit to your question.

Comment: Once you have edited your question, you may comment on people's answers to alert them of the edit.

Comment: Ahh okay, sorry :(  Didn't realize the protocol, my apologies.  I wasn't trying to piss anyone off... I just wasn't sure how to alert people to the slightly inaccurate nature of this answer... I actually ended up following your suggestion accidentally, so that's good at least!  The clarification to [Jens] is currently a note in my question! Will peek at the edits queue in the future to avoid to inaccurate remarks!

Comment: One question for you sarnold... (you'll earn another upvote from me if you can help me by answering...) How do you know what the # is for the "suggested-edits" is... I can see the queue you posted, however the # is different than the question #.  Where does that # come from?